# Change foreground color of ObservableCollection element in wpf - C#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have following rangeobservablecollection:

```
private readonly RangeObservableCollection<coll> _coll;
```

where coll is bunch of checkboxes that i am adding to this collection. I want to change the foreground color of the checkbox on particular add like this:

```
_coll.Add( info );
```

Is there a way to change the color of this?

XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0" Foreground="{Binding Foreground"}">
                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                        <Binding Path="IsSelected"
                                 Mode="TwoWay">
                            <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                <RelativeSource Mode="Parent" />
                            </Binding.RelativeSource>
                        </Binding>
                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                </CheckBox>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: `coll` is a type that inherits from `CheckBox`, or `coll` is an entity bound to an `ItemsControl` of `CheckBoxes`?

Comment: You should really use CamelCasing for class names.

Comment: Create an extension method which changes color and then adds to the collection...

Comment: coll has a property that you want to control the color when bound to a checkbox? You should probably add a bit more context such as XAML bindings...

Comment: @Baboon - coll is entity bound to an ItemsControl of checkboxes.

Comment: Do you have access to the entity coll to add a foreground property to it which you could then bind to the CheckBox.Foreground property on your data template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a template on your ui object that binds the foreground color to a SolidColorBrush property on coll class.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" Content="{Binding Description}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

your class definition will look something like this:

```
public class coll
{
    public IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Foreground { get; set; }
}
```

then you can change the foreground:

```
info.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
_coll.Add( info );
```

There's a lot of variations you can use here to achieve the same effect: converters, INPC...

Comment: +1 although the color should be derived from a more useful property.

Comment: @Salvador Sarpi - I have added my xaml code can you suggest a solution on based of that? I tried making above changes but am new to xaml and not sure how to incorporate those in my code?

Comment: @Baboon yes, that's the use i would give to converters, but you get the idea.

Comment: @NoviceMe if you added a SolidColorBrush property to your class, you should change <CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0"> to <CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0" Foreground="{Binding YourForegroundProperty}">

Comment: @SalvadorSarpi - What will be YourForegroundProperty in this case?? Where do we call this or reference this? Should i replace Foreground with YourForegroundProperty in this?               public SolidColorBrush Foreground { get; set; }

Comment: If you named Foreground the solidcolorbrush property then you should use that name in the binding {Binding Foreground}

Comment: @SalvadorSarpi - Sorry to keep on disturbing you. But i tried changing the Binding to Foreground. But still it is not working? Can you please help? Color of text is not changing.

Comment: @SalvadorSarpi - Actually can you tell how to associate class col with Foreground binding?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19781/discussion-between-salvador-sarpi-and-noviceme)